# storing to a file and retrieving the content of a file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code I built following a tutorial and I am successfully stored to a file. I checked the file physically to ensure the info is there and it is. But retrieving it is giving me a hard time. I have stared at it for hours and can't find anything wrong with it. If you follow the steps 2 - 2 1 - 5 - 9 and re-run it and then do step 6 - 1 You will notice the first set of steps are fine the second set of menu options are not.

This is what I have.

team.py class file

```
#Team class definition

class Team:

    #initializing object

    def __init__(self, name, phone, jersey):

        self.__name = name

        self.__phone = phone

        self.__jersey = jersey


    #mutator methods

    def setname(self, name):

        self.__name = name

    def setphone(self, phone):

        self.__phone = phone

    def setjersey(self, jersey):

        self.__jersey = jersey



    #accessor methods

    def getname(self):

        return self.__name

    def getphone(self):

        return self.__phone

    def getjersey(self):

        return self.__jersey


    #display template for output
    def displayData(self):

        print("")

        print("Team information: ")

        print("------------------------")

        print("Member's Name:", self.__name)

        print("Phone Number:", self.__phone)

        print("Jersey Number:", self.__jersey)
```

members.py program file

```
# program functions and import data

import team


def displayMenu():
    print("===========Main Menu===========")

    print("1. Team Roster.")

    print("2. Add Member.")

    print("3. Remove Member.")

    print("4. Edit Member.")

    print("5. Save Data.")

    print("6. Load Data.")

    print("9. Exit Program.")

    print("")

    return int(input("Selection> "))

def printMember(members):
    if len(members) == 0:

        print("No members in roster yet.")

    else:

        for x in members.keys():
            members[x].displayData()

def addMember(members):
    newName = input("Enter new member's name: ")

    newPhone = int(input("Enter member's phone number: "))

    newJersey = input("Enter member's jersey number: ")

    members[newName] = team.Team(newName, newPhone, newJersey)

    return members

def removeMember(members):
    removeName = input("Enter the member's name you wish to remove: ")

    if removeName in members:

        del members[removeName]

        print("\nYou've removed ", removeName)

    else:

        print("This name is not in our records.")

    return members

def editMember(members):

    oldName = input("Enter the name of the member you want to edit: ")

    if oldName in members:

        newName = input("Enter the member's new name: ")

        newPhone = int(input("Enter the member's new phone number: "))

        newJersey = input("Enter the member's new jersey number: ")

        members[oldName] = team.Team(newName, newPhone, newJersey)

    else:

        print("Member does not exist")

    return members

def saveData(members):

    filename = input("Filename to save: ")

    print("Saving data...")

    outFile = open(filename, "wt")

    for x in members.keys():

        name = members[x].getname()

        phone = str(members[x].getphone())

        jersey = members[x].getjersey()

        outFile.write(name + "," + phone + "," + jersey + "\n")

    print("Data saved.")

    outFile.close()

def loadData():

    members = {}

    filename = input("Filename to load: ")

    inFile = open(filename, "rt")

    print("Loading data...")

    while True:

        # read in a line of text from the text file

        inLine = inFile.readline()

        # if line is empty, stop loading data.

        if not inLine:

            break

        inLine = inLine[:-1]

        name, phone, jersey = inLine.split(",")

        members[name] = team.Team(name, phone, jersey)

    print("Data Loaded Successfully.")

    inFile.close()

    return members

# Running the program

print("Welcome to the Team Manager")

members = {}

menuSelection = displayMenu()

while menuSelection != 9:

    if menuSelection == 1:

        printMember(members)


    elif menuSelection == 2:

        members = addMember(members)


    elif menuSelection == 3:

        members = removeMember(members)


    elif menuSelection == 4:

        members = editMember(members)

    elif menuSelection == 5:

        filename = saveData(members)

    elif menuSelection == 6:

        filename = loadData()

    menuSelection = displayMenu()

print("Exiting Program...")
```

Help me or I'll become an alcoholic :) haha Here is the [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/U6ZIyV)

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: I normally do @cricket_007 but last time I did this I got my butt chewed out for not putting the whole program. Unfortunately, everything or mostly everything is needed. I could simplify it I guess, but not much. As you can see the steps all take different methods and I would have to put them here or no one would be able to run it and debug it. If it becomes a problem, I'll rewrite it with one question only.

Comment: Well, your question is load and save, right? So, why did you show everything else?

Comment: @cricket_007 you must add something to it so that the file can contain something to read and return when loaded. That's what step 1 and 2 does. I figured you'd need it to test it correctly.

Comment: My advice would be to stop using this tutorial. It looks like it was made by a Java programmer with no Python experience (the use of getters and setters, and name-mangling for no reason, and the use of camel case instead of snake case)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'll take the blame for the camel casing. I'm an angular developer so I'm used to it. But the getter setters is a good point. You're the second person who says that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saveData returns nothing, not the filename

```
filename = saveData(members)
```

loadData does not return the filename, it returns the members.

```
filename = loadData()
```

I'd suggest researching how global variables work in Python. You only need one instance of `members`.

If you're looking for a better way to perform the CRUD operations, use sqlite module of Python

And, by the way, Pycharm has a useful debugger.

Comment: I don't think I follow. My code shows it the same way as what you suggested.

Comment: are you saying it shouldn't be 'filename = loadData()' but 'members = loadData()' instead?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying. I'm pointing out your mistakes. How you chose to fix it, is up to you. I trust your ability to debug these issues

Comment: I used members as a parameter or attribute in the method and called it as such in later and it still didn't work. By the way, I am trying not to get ahead of myself with this Udemy tutorial by using things more advanced. I'm sure I'll get there in due time. This code is supposed to work with the exception of whatever I messed up of course lol

Comment: You don't need parameters. You also should not modify your parameters. Such a method definition causes "side effects" and is never good

Comment: That is very good to know. And you're right, parameters didn't help anyway. Thanks for your help. It works now.